# Elastic 6.2 writing data to the wrong index

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I need to update a mapping with additional fields, but decided to create an experimental mapping first and write documents to it to weed out the problems.

Here, the original is:

```
"index": "bookmark",
"type": "bookmark"
```

... and the experiment is:

```
"index": "experiment",
"type": "experiment"
```

As it happened, the whole thing worked first time of asking, but then the next document didn't, instead writing to the "bookmark" index.

I've spent a few hours changing the names of the indexes and types, and while it sometimes writes to the "experiment" index once or perhaps several times, it's then switch to "bookmark" without ever reverting.

In the application, there are two references to the index and type, and both are passed as an array into the class that handles the Elastic work.

If delete the "data" array for the document to be passed to Elastic, it won't write data, which — I suppose — should be obvious, but then under *normal* circumstances, it's ignoring the "meta_information" object, the index, and the type.

It's worth noting this is a mature application that's been using Elastic without error since 5.6.

This behaviour is inexplicable, and — according to the code — impossible, too.

In terms of differences between the two mappings, the experiment: has an additional "nested" object; and a different "type".

I'm using Elastic 6.2.4, and Kibana of the same version.

As requested, here's is the mapping for the "experiment" index:

`PUT localhost:9200/experiment`

```
{
    "settings":{
        "analysis":{
            "char_filter":{
                "&_to_and":{
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": ["&=> and "]
                }
            },
            "filter":{
                "asset_en_stopwords":{
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": ["_english_"]
                },
                "asset_en_stemmer":{
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "name": "english"
                },
                "asset_en_shingle":{
                    "type": "shingle",
                    "max_shingle_size": 5,
                    "min_shingle_size": 2,
                    "output_unigrams": false,
                    "output_unigrams_if_no_shingles": true
                }
            },
            "analyzer":{
                "asset_en_analyzer":{
                    "type": "custom",
                    "char_filter": ["html_strip", "&_to_and"],
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["asset_en_stopwords", "asset_en_stemmer", "lowercase", "asset_en_shingle", "asciifolding"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings":{
        "experiment":{
            "properties":{
                "user_id":{
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "creation":{
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "deleted":{
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "favourite":{
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "modification":{
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "note":{
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "english",
                    "fields":{
                        "std":{
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "asset_en_analyzer",
                            "fields":{
                                "std":{
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "analyzer": "standard"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "title":{
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "english",
                    "fields":{
                        "std":{
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "asset_en_analyzer",
                            "fields":{
                                "std":{
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "analyzer": "standard"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "links_to_asset":{
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties":{
                        "note_link_id":{
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "user_id":{
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "creation":{
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                        },
                        "modification":{
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                        },
                        "to_asset":{
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "from_asset":{
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "comment":{
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields":{
                                "std":{
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "analyzer": "asset_en_analyzer",
                                    "fields":{
                                        "std":{
                                            "type": "text",
                                            "analyzer": "standard"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "meta_information":{
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties":{
                        "entities":{
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties":{
                                "name":{
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields":{
                                        "std":{
                                            "type": "text",
                                            "analyzer": "asset_en_analyzer",
                                            "fields":{
                                                "std":{
                                                    "type": "text",
                                                    "analyzer": "standard"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "type":{  
                                    "type":"keyword"
                                },
                                "salience":{
                                    "type":"integer"
                                },
                                "metadata":{
                                    "type": "nested",
                                    "properties":{
                                        "wikipedia_url":{
                                            "type": "keyword"
                                        },
                                        "mid":{
                                            "type": "keyword"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "sentiment":{
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties":{
                                "score":{
                                    "type":"integer"
                                },
                                "magnitude":{
                                    "type":"integer"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url":{
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "publication_date":{
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... where the one difference between it and "bookmarks" is the `meta_information` nested object type.

Also, here's the code that writes the data:

```
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $this->flexi_auth->get_user_id(),
        'title' => strip_tags( $title ),
        'note' => strip_tags( $note ),
        'creation' => str_replace( ' ', 'T', date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ),
        'modification' => str_replace( ' ', 'T', date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ),
        'publication_date' => $date,
        'url' => $url,
        'links_to_asset' => [],
        'meta_information' => [
            'entities' => $metaInformation['entities'],
            'sentiment' => $metaInformation['sentiment']
        ],
        'favourite' => 0,
        'deleted' => 0
    );

    $params = array(
        'index' => "experiment",
        'type' => "experiment",
        'id' => $note_id
    );

    $this->elasticsearch_model->addAssetData(
        $data, $params
    );
```

... and in the model:

```
public function addAssetData ($data, $params) {
    try {
        if (!isset($params['index']) || !isset($params['type']))
            die ("Unable to add Elastic index for an Asset. Either index or type is not defined.");

        $client = $this->_client;

        foreach ($data as $_id => $insert) {
            $params['body'][$_id] = $insert;
        }

        $responses = $client->index($params);

        return $responses;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Here is where Elastic intervenes, *sometimes* choosing to write the data based on these parameters, then — after a while, and at random — ignoring the `meta_information` array and switching to the index: "bookmarks" and type: "bookmark".

I'm also using [the official Elastic PHP package](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

I've used `var_dump($data, $params)` countless times and the values are correct, but whether Elastic chooses to use that data is in the lap of the gods.

Comment: Can you post queries that you have been using for indexing data. Also, providing mapping would help

Comment: Done, but this appears to be a problem with Elastic and not the application.

Comment: I reverted the index and type and now I'm getting an: `index_not_found_exception` for the "experiment" index, so there appears to be some caching in Elastic, which I would imagine is the cause of the problem.